# Use custom external style property in React

Tags: excel, reactjs

In my React app I'm exporting a html table to Excel by saving the rendered html (which Excel knows how to open) to a file. I'm also trying to set 'mso-number-format' style property on each `<td>` to tell Excel what number format to use per cell. However, React doesn't like this code:

```
<td style={{ 'mso-number-format': '\\@' }}
```

In console it logs:

```
Unsupported style property mso-number-format. Did you mean msoNumberFormat? Check the render method of `ComponentX`.
```

Is there a way to get around this without traversing the DOM and manually do something like:

```
node.setAttribute('style', 'mso-number-format: \\@')
```

Comment: any updates on this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Styles attributes in React JSX are written in camelCase notation and not as you have defined. Define it like

```
<td style={{ 'msoNumberFormat': '\@' }}>
```

The docs in react says this

> In React, inline styles are not specified as a string. Instead they
>   are specified with an object whose key is the camelCased version of
>   the style name, and whose value is the style's value, usually a string
>
> Style keys are camelCased in order to be consistent with accessing the
>   properties on DOM nodes from JS (e.g. node.style.backgroundImage).
>   Vendor prefixes other than ms should begin with a capital letter. This
>   is why WebkitTransition has an uppercase "W".

**[Inline styles docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html)**

as react suggests you to and it will solve your problem.

Also I think it should be a  `\@` instead of `\\@` for text formatting.

You can also try it as

```
var styles = {
    msoNumberFormat: '\@'
}

<td style={styles}>
```

Comment: Yes I did try <td style={{ 'msoNumberFormat': '\\@' }}> and the warning disappears but the style is not getting rendered in the <td>:s

Comment: Try the edit ans see if it displays in your elements css when you try to inspect the element. Also I think there should be a single \@ instead of \\@

Comment: Can't make it fly, see here how color: red is being applied to cells but not mso-number-format: https://jsfiddle.net/pichdude/dce0ygu2/2/